# Finding Covariance from linear algebra projection chapter

Tags: least-squares, covariance, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, projection

I am trying to solid background of linear regression by using linear algebra.
In linear algebra, there are some chapters that related to linear regression. (orthogonality, Projection)

I learned some facts.

When we assume that **Ax=b** is not solvable. we project **b** onto column space of A, which is **p**.
so we find Ax^=p

A is m by n matrix.

1. b=p+e / e=b-p / e=b-Ax^
2. e is perpendicular to C(A) (column space of A) / e is in leftnull space of A
3. A'(b-Ax^)=0 / A'Ax^=A'b
4. Thus, x^= inverse(A'A)A'b
5. p= Ainverse(A'A)A'b
6. E = e1^2+e2^2+..........+em^2

I know when A=(1,..........,1) has only 1 column, x^=sum(b1,..........,bm)/m = mean of b.

Number 13,14 questions are the problems.

1. why e=b-Ax not e=b-Ax^ ?
2. why the off-diagonal entries are zero in ee' matrix?

I really would like to know the intuition behind this process. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Hi: When you do the projection, your $x$ doesn't change to $x^{\prime}$. It's still just the same as the original $x$. (so they put $p$ so that the equality still holds because it does not hold in the case of $b$. ).The off diagonals are zero due to one of the OLS assumptions which is that residuals are independent so covariances are zero.